# email id validation in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net

In my web application i have a textbox with multiline property is true, when ever i type emailids separating with comma how can i validate multiple emailid in this situation.

like: sasidhar@yahoo.com,surya@gmail.com in a textbox  how can i validate please help me

Comment: Split on comma, then validate each email address in turn (probably with a regex). Which bit are you stuck on? What have you tried so far?

Comment: You understand that validation simply checks the e-mail fits rules, not that it is actually correct with a recipient at the end (thats verification)?

Answer (score 1):

Here's the general idea:

Split the values and store it into an array, then validate it using (I recommend this): http://www.coveryourasp.com/ShowSource.asp?page=ValidateEmail